# How to send automated message in Whatsapp using python?

Tags: python, whatsapp

My requirement is to send WhatsApp message to number present in the Mobile number column whenever a new user record is created in User table. This will be a welcome message.

When a new user register on the website, I need to send automated welcome message to the registered mobile number.

I tried https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/whatsapp-using-python/ but this is using selenium and need manual intervention to scan the QR code.

I am looking for a solution where no manual intervention should be there.

Comment: So what is your solution so far?

Comment: @Melon I have mentioned that in my question.

Comment: Any code you can present?

Comment: Click on the link. You can see the code.

Comment: you should explain to us what you have tried by yourself so far (not a generic tutorial), where are you stuck precisely or which part of your code doesn't work... so we can really help

Comment: @JMax i tried the code in the link. But I need a pointer for the alternative solution without user interaction. If you are not able to understand this you may not be able to help. A person who understood the problem has already answered to this thread. I am already trying it out.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this using Twilio Whatsapp API for python.

Refer this link:
https://www.twilio.com/docs/sms/whatsapp/quickstart/python

It is a fully automated process and does not require manual intervention unlike selenium.

Comment: Thanks Adhi. Will try and let you know.